# My book says “binding energy is the energy released when a nucleus is created from another nuclei or nucleons”

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

According to my book “binding energy is the energy released when a nucleus is formed from nuclei or nucleons.This nuclear binding energy is derived from nuclear force “. How is the binding energy DERIVED from nuclear force

Comment: Not quite clear what you are asking. For example, how do you consider the binding energy of the moon to the Earth and gravity?

Comment: Binding energy is released when nucleons come together, right? If it’s released, it’s not a part of the nucleus formed. Then, how is the nuclear force a SOURCE OF binding energy? (Acc to the book)

Answer (score 3):

Your book is unclear. It needs a descriptive "which":

*"Binding energy, which is released when a nucleus is formed, is the energy that is derived from the nuclear force."*

While it reads like a definitive "that":

*"Binding energy is the energy that is released when a nucleus if formed, which is derived from the nuclear force."*

The simplest explanation of binding energy is a golf ball in the cup: it's bound to the hole with $mgh$, and it takes energy to remove it and put it back on the green (a higher energy state for the green/ball/cup system).

Of course, $mgh \ll mc^2$, so there's not much to say about it.

The simplest multi-nucleon nucleus is the deuteron: a bound proton and neutron. Far apart (and at rest):

$$ m_p = 938.27\,{\rm MeV/c^2} $$
$$ m_n = 939.56\,{\rm MeV/c^2} $$

so the total energy of the system is $m_p + m_n$. In the deuteron, they are bound together by an attractive force, and mass is:

$$ M_d = 1875.61\,{\rm MeV/c^2} $$

which is $2.2\,{\rm MeV/c^2} $ less than the sum of the constituents masses. That is the binding energy. You need to input that energy to break them apart.

Answer (score 0):

The nucleus is formed of the nucleons. They, at the small dimension of nucleus ($ about\  10^{-14}$) are held together by Nuclear forces. The binding energy means the amount of energy which is required to hold them together (as expected from the name). So clearly **the source of binding energy comes all the way from Nuclear forces**. And hence we require that amount of energy to separate all the nucleons completely from the nucleus.

On the other hand the energy released when nucleus is formed from nucleons comes from the difference between the total mass of the nucleons and the mass of the created nucleus (known as mass defect).

They are related in the way that : **If you give that mass defect amount of energy to the nucleus, it will most likely disintegrate again. Now refer to the last line in the first paragraph. From these you can tell that binding energy and that defect energy are connected by this way.**

For the rigorous derivations for the binding energy you can refer to other books which uses the semi empirical mass formula.

Comment: The amount of energy that “needs to be released to bind the nucleons”, right?

Comment: Yes. That's the mass defect or technically the binding energy

Answer (score 0):

I will like to tell you this concept in a much more reasonable and understandable way.
Lets try to unserstand a very simple case first. What happens when you throw a ball up in the sky? You may answer well it goes up and come down but there is a very interseting thing happening in the time interval when ball is going up.The kinetic energy you provided to the ball gets converted into potential energy. Something same happens with a nucleus. lets say we made a really,really hot plasma(wanna say -Imagine), what happens there is that the nuclei are moving really fast such that they can overcome the coulomb barrier(Sufficient energy to overcome repulsion between nuclei to a distace after which the strong nuclear force takes over.). I will like to pin point another thing- strong force and strong nuclear force are not the same thing.(the reason is that it is both the force are mediated by diffrent particles.Strong force by gluons and Strong nuclear force by mesons.).Till this time our ball analogy works well as it is the same as thing. The kinetic energy of nuclei is getting converted in the potential energy. But once it reaches the range of about ≈$(10^-(14))$m , but after reaching this distance something happens , the king of all forces(Strong "Nuclear" force is awake) starts doing it's job and pull all the particles togeather. The actual mechanism of this process is explained by **Quantum Chromodynamics(QCD)**(Let's forget we even talk about it).This picture shows the potential energy v/s distance curve in case of Strong Nuclear force.
[image]

You may notice that at a certain distace the potential energy is negative. But you also know that system had a intial energy which was positive and by conservation of momentum you can say that **Energy is released into the environment** .This energy is released in the form of kinetic energy of the entire nucleus(or many other options such as excitation is also possible).**This Energy which is released is called Binding energy**.
I hope that my answer would have pleased you.

Answer (score 0):

When 2 nucleons are bound they have lower energy than when they are seperated due to the attractive nuclear force so by conservation of energy they release heat.In QCD quarks have colors which are just like charges and there are 3 types of colors(red,blue and green).There are gluons(or more accurately pions) which are like photons and mediate the nuclear force.But unlike photons the pions also have a charge themselves and this results in a exponential potential function.